# Why was the development of mathematics very slow between Ancient Greece and Descartes?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, ancient-greece, book-recommendation, middle-ages

### I asked this question on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844970/why-the-development-of-mathematics-was-very-slow-between-ancient-greece-and-desc?noredirect=1#comment10321017_4844970)

---

In my studies of mathematics (I am not very good at mathematics, I only studied real analysis, some linear algebra, geometry and calculus ), I noticed that mathematics can be divided into two major parts. One part is Ancient Greek mathematics . This part has achievements in geometry and arithmetic and their connections. The other part is modern mathematics from Descartes to today. This part has discoveries in calculus, number theory, topology, and many other fields (areas). But what happened between these two eras? In my studies, I did not find many theorems from this period or any great breakthrough at all.

It seems like mathematics stopped there and only resumed in the 1500s and 1600s here I am not talking about European mathematics but mathematics in general (Middle East, China, India, etc.). But why is that? Mathematics is not an empirical science like physics that needs experiments to test theories and wait for centuries such that their tools become good enough. Mathematics only relies on logic, and for some reason Mathematics was just like other empirical sciences -- it began really to develop after the 1600s.

As far as I know, mathematics can be divided into fields (areas) like topology, analysis, number theory, algebra, geometry, combinatorics, etc. Most of these fields or areas took more than a millennium to appear. The first major one was geometry, and it appeared in Ancient Greece. All the others did not exist until after the 1600s, like topology or analysis, or they were too small and narrow to be considered as separate fields before. So why is that? Even if calculus took 1000 years to be discovered (Which I don't know why! see [This question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/16129/what-were-the-obstacles-that-made-the-discovery-of-calculus-very-late)  ) I heard that many mathematical fields don't rely on analysis very much, like abstract algebra, graph theory, etc.

I heard that philosophy held back mathematics for millennia, Archimedes could have discovered calculus if he did not think too much about philosophy and infinity.  Is this the reason?

So why was the development of mathematics slow for a millennium  and why did many mathematical concepts take millennia to develop? or in other words why the development of mathematics was very slow between Ancient Greece and Descartes (I don't mean Descartes specifically but the era that he lived in. Cavalieri, Fermat, Kepler, etc. were from the same era, i.e., 1550−1650
.)

I think this question might  have too long answers  as a user point out before in one of my old questions:  "You must realize that the history of mathematics is not going to be broken down into a couple of paragraphs," and so I will ask for books or references that answer this question if the answer is too long.

Comment: Did you miss all contribution from Islamic Middle Ages and India? Algebra, polynomial equations, cubic roots, modern numerals, negative numbers, trigonometric functions and much more came from that period

Comment: @Mauricio No I know many of them I am saying that in my study of math from elementary school to college math 99% of the theorems that I studied was from ancient Greek ( and every thing before that) era and the modern era. even the theorems that I haven't studied yet and just heard of it there is not much of them in this era and I didn't know if this era has a great breakthrough and even if there were some of them, I think there were not very relevant  or not very important now since in the modern era there is not much of these theorem is taught in schools or college.

Comment: and most of math area like analysis , number theory , topology etc only appeared recently and the only field that appeared before 1500s is geometry and it appeared in ancient greek era

Comment: I think you are just dismissing it because they are sometimes not correctly attributed in Western learning. But the history of mathematics shows a continuous flow from Greek sources to Medieval Islam and back to Europe. Are you telling me that Al-Khwarizmi solution for quadratic equations was not consequential? Algebra is a major topic in math from that era.

Comment: Even if you dismiss modern numerals, trigonometry and algebra, Wikipedia also cites:   al-Kindi's introduction of cryptanalysis and frequency analysis, the development of analytic geometry, the beginning of algebraic geometry and the development of an algebraic notation

Comment: @Mauricio I am from Middle east BTW (Egypt) and I am trying to say that mathematics between 1600s to now has developed a lot there are many new areas theorems and a lot  and math in 2024 has developed a lot since math from 1900 and the math from 1900s has developed a lot since 1800s and so on but If I tried to ask what is the difference between 1100s math and 1200s I don't think there is a lot of development and I think this is the same case with greek math every 100 year will be some difference

Maybe I am wrong

Comment: Maybe I am wrong  But for what I know math for some reason was just like other since (physics, chemistry , etc ) that only started rally  to develop after 1600s But math is much different in 2 things 1- math has a great development in ancient era 2- Mathematics is not like physics that needs experiments to test theories and wait for centuries such that their tools become good enough.

Comment: When your say that mathematics "is not like physics that needs experiments" and it "only relies on logic", you seem to underestimate its connections with other fields and with society (or the reasons we do math in the first place). A lot of development in math from 1600s onwards can be attributed to developments in physics, engineering, astronomy, etc.

Comment: As with most areas of science, they evolve in some kind of exponential way in modern times. So most areas of mathematics in a math dictionary right now are from last century. The problem of middle ages are records, for some reasons we kept very good records of Greek math but mathematicians did not translate, preserve and attribute as much fro Middle Ages as somebody would have done with modern sources. Probably this shift from Europe to outside Europe might also have play a role in this supposedly slow down of progress. Additionally are you considering European Renaissance math to be slow?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz But pure math can be developed without all of these Right ? and I think that you are right here because it seems to be a very reasonable answer But why no one tried to develop math outside of the real world applications? and why fields like analysis or topology or number theory came that late? As far as I know the motivation for these areas were not something "new" and didn't involve a lot of real applications  and the only major area that appeared was geometry ?

Comment: @pie there were some calculus pioneers from that time see [Kerala School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala_school_of_astronomy_and_mathematics). Number theory also needed arithmetic from that time. People like Fibonacci appeared long before Descartes. However some of these results were probably less famous because of their lack of direct applicability. At that time, if something was useful there were more chances for it to be kept.

Comment: We have to consider the complexity of historical events... Today we are accustomed to think in term of *progress*: an ever growing progress that accumulates knowledge. But "modern progress" lasted since Renaissance: about 500 years. Ancient Greece culture lasted from 500 BC to 300 AC (around 800 years). The "Dark Ages" covered in Europe several centuries, but in the meantime there were mathematics living in Islam, including some part of Europe, Baghdad, etc. And there is India, China. Historical facts are consistent with the possibility that there are "waves" of growing and decay...

Comment: As this is now a book recomendation question could you narrow down the question again? Do you need academic sources on  Medieval World math? Middle Ages Europe math? History of math? or book specifically centered about the idea of decline in Middle Ages science?

Comment: @Mauricio This is not  book recommendation question "and so I will ask for books or reference that answer this question if the answer is too long." but any way I think  Medieval World math, book specifically centred about the idea of decline in Middle Ages **Math** would be great

Comment: @pie A fascinating book I recently found is Series and Products in the Development of Mathematics by Ranjan Roy. Many formulas for pi were discovered from antiquity to modern math.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer:

Was there a gap of knowledge or slow-down of progress in math as a whole between Ancient Greeks and the 17th century?

The answer is probably no.

[Islamic Medieval World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_in_the_medieval_Islamic_world) and [Medieval India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_mathematics) contributed greatly to math during the Middle Ages. The fields of algebra, polynomial equations, cubic roots, modern numerals, logic, negative numbers, trigonometric functions and much more came from that period. These contributions are not minor and contributed continuously to the development of math. Islamic sources in particular translated and preserved a lot of Ancient Greek and Indian sources, and Islamic sources were later used by Renaissance Europeans like Fibonacci.

Wikipedia's [history of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematics) also cites:

> Other achievements of Muslim mathematicians during this period include the addition of the decimal point notation to the Arabic numerals, the discovery of all the modern trigonometric functions besides the sine, al-Kindi's introduction of cryptanalysis and frequency analysis, the development of analytic geometry by Ibn al-Haytham, the beginning of algebraic geometry by Omar Khayyam and the development of an algebraic notation by al-Qalasādī.

As for well known theorems of this time you have: the law of cosines (a.k.a. Al-Kashi's theorem), Chinese remainder theorem, Merton mean speed theorem, Wilson's theorem, Thabit's rule, divergence of the harmonic series,  and the binomial theorem.

But even if we forget the Middle Ages as some "Dark Ages" (a term now considered as misnomer) and focus on Europe, we still have the whole Renaissance. People like Tartaglia and Cardano helped develop the solution to the quartic equations. Bombelli developed the algebra of imaginary numbers.

Many theses could be written on why the developments between Ancient Greeks and 17th century math seem "slow" or minor. I propose three conjectures:

1. Lack of proper sources and attribution: sources foreign to Europe were not translated or properly attributed. This makes a lot of contributions that have no authors attached to them (even if we have words like *algebra* that come from Arabic or *algorithm* which comes from Al-Khwarizmi).
2. Utility: Some mathematical content is preserved and transferred to the next generation better than others. Most of the time if there is some application (engineering, physics or astronomy) there was a higher chance for the content to survive. [Kerala School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala_school_of_astronomy_and_mathematics) might have invented calculus, but clearly their results were never largely popularized (maybe even never left Kerala).
3. Transition of power: As Europe declined in the Middle Ages and the Medieval Islamic World became an important center of knowledge and power, clearly there was a lot of friction. Text had to be translated from Greek and Latin (and Sanskrit from India) to Arabic - and when Europe "reemerged", back from Arabic to Latin. Religious conflicts and other power struggles also did not help. Imagine how hard it was to introduce Hindu decimal numerals from the Indian subcontinent into West Asia and into Europe without the Internet, printing, long distance sailing and so on. Nevertheless, it made the trip because it was an important breakthrough.

However for every reason that I can find for this possible setback in progress in math, I can find a ton of contributions from those times that make the setback negligible. How much importance we give to these developments over some more recent ones is more a matter of opinion or perspective - though this is not the forum for opinion-based discussions.

The Dark Ages is a myth. For a light read, check for example *The Light Ages: The Surprising Story of Medieval Science* by Seb Falk  ([*Time* excerpt](https://time.com/5911003/middle-ages-myths/)), and *The West: A New History in Fourteen Lives* by Naoíse Mac Sweeney ([Smithsonian excerpt](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/the-myth-of-the-dark-ages-ignores-how-classical-traditions-flourished-around-the-world-180982190/)).

MathSE recommends *[A Short Account of the History of Mathematics](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31246)* by W. W. Rouse Ball for the history of math in general. It divides all math in three great periods: Ancient Greeks, Middle Ages and Renaissance, and Modern (beginning with Descartes). Chapters cover math from the last period of the Roman Empire, Middle Ages math (both in Islamic and Europe) and Renaissance math.

I end by adding this good quote I found in [MacTutor History of Mathematics Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacTutor_History_of_Mathematics_Archive) article on "[Arabic mathematics](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Arabic_mathematics/)":

> There is a widely held view that, after a brilliant period for mathematics when the Greeks laid the foundations for modern mathematics, there was a period of stagnation before the Europeans took over where the Greeks left off at the beginning of the sixteenth century. The common perception of the period of 1000 years or so between the ancient Greeks and the European Renaissance is that little happened in the world of mathematics except that some Arabic translations of Greek texts were made which preserved the Greek learning so that it was available to the Europeans at the beginning of the sixteenth century.
>
> That such views should be generally held is of no surprise. Many leading historians of mathematics have contributed to the perception by either omitting any mention of Arabic/Islamic mathematics in the historical development of the subject or with statements such as that made by Duhem in [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematics):-
>
> > ... Arabic science only reproduced the teachings received from Greek science.

> Certainly many of the ideas which were previously thought to have been brilliant new conceptions due to European mathematicians of the sixteenth, seventeenth and eighteenth centuries are now known to have been developed by Arabic/Islamic mathematicians around four centuries earlier. In many respects the mathematics studied today is far closer in style to that of the Arabic/Islamic contribution than to that of the Greeks.

Comment: The invention of the [printing press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press) in the mid 1400s played a crucial role in the acceleration of scholarly work. For what it's worth, I think there are a lot of parallels with the rise of the internet beginning in the mid 1990s. Both brought about faster and wider dissemination of information, more outlets for scholarly writing, more lower quality stuff getting through $\ldots$

Comment: @DaveLRenfro certainly the speed of progress is changing and accelerating.  Much more math is produced now than a century ago, more math was produced in the 20th century compared to the 19th century and so on. But I think that is the way no matter the century, I do not see what's special about the Middle Ages in terms of acceleration. It never  "stopped" as OP wrote originally in his question.

Comment: To go off on a tangent (ha!), what do you mean by “The Dark Ages is a myth”?  That there were a few centuries when nothing much happened and no advances were made?  Or that there were a few centuries when we don't have much written evidence and so don't _know_ much about what happened or what advances were made?  — AIUI, the first is indeed a myth, but one that hasn't been widely taught or believed for a good while; and the second is mostly valid.  (‘Dark’ meaning unknown, rather than lacking light; the same misconception that's sometimes applied to ‘the dark side of the Moon’.)

Comment: @gidds the Dark Ages is the idea that due to the decline of Rome, the Middle Ages had little to no advancement in knowledge and science. Many authors have written against this idea. The Middle Ages saw a lot of progress (mainly outside Europe but in Europe too!).

Comment: I wonder if many mathematical contributions from the Islamic world was lost due to mongol destruction of Baghdad House of Wisdom?

Comment: @gidds: The notion that we don't have much written evidence from the so-called Dark Ages is also debatable at best. The medievalists Matthew Gabriele and David M. Perry have recently written a popular book, *The Bright Ages: A New History of Medieval Europe*, that you may be interested in. (The "bright" of the title means "well-lit" more than "wonderful", though the authors do also emphasize that the Middle Ages were much better than most people assume today.)

Comment: @pie according to legend (written some centuries after), "so many manuscripts were tossed into the River Tigris that its waters turned black from ink". We can only wonder.

Comment: In Series and Products in the Development of Mathematics by Ranjan Roy, he mentions much of the work of the medieval Kerala astronomers never made it out of India or even Kerala.

Comment: @ruakh Debateable or not, the meaning of the term 'dark ages' here is about a lack of knowledge about the time, not that it was 'bad' or that no developments were made.  It's the same usage that astronomers use when they talk about the 'dark ages' of the formation of the universe: a period of time where there's little to no available information.

Comment: Fibonacci formative years were about 1185-1200. A prosperous time in medieval Europe, but definitely too early to count as Renaissance.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I'm not sure why you direct your comment at me — your comment doesn't really bear on what I wrote — but FWIW, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Ages_%28historiography%29. The term "Dark Ages" did not originally, and does not primarily, imply what you suggest.

Comment: @ruakh "I'm not sure why you direct your comment at me", because you wrote: "The notion that we don't have much written evidence from the so-called Dark Ages is also debatable at best."  You might want to look at the link you used as eviddence.  It contains the following: "Significantly, Baronius termed the age 'dark' because of the paucity of written records."

Comment: @ruakh I do concede that the term has been used both ways and originally meant 'bad'.  From the  wikipedia page you referenced: "Baronius' 'dark age' seems to have struck historians, for it was in the 17th century that the term started to spread to various European languages, ... Some, following Baronius, used 'dark age' neutrally to refer to a dearth of written records, but others used it pejoratively and lapsed into that lack of objectivity that has discredited the term for many modern historians."

Comment: Re "Renaissance Europeans like Fibonacci" Fibonacci lived roughly from 1170-1250, during the High Middle Ages. His *Liber Abaci* dates to 1202. The Renaissance did not start until the 14th century.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematics is a tiny part of human activities, and its historical development cannot be considered in isolation.
Since the 2nd century AD, there was a decline in all intellectual activities. Eventually civilization itself collapsed, and its slow revival started only in  16th century. In this period, people mostly lived in the villages,
rather than in large cities, most of the economy was on subsistence level, most people were illiterate, technology was lost, and the main
intellectual activity was concern about afterlife.

This was not the only such collapse of which we have historical evidence: another one on a similar scale happened around 1200 BC. Historians discuss a lot the reasons of these collapses, the literature on the topic is enormous, and there is no common opinion.

Let me mention just a few books, and one modern paper.

- Edward Gibbon, The decline and fall of the Roman empire.
- Peter Heather, The Fall of the Roman Empire: A New History of Rome and the Barbarians, Oxford, 2006.
- Brian Ward-Perkins, The fall of Rome and the end of civilization, Oxford UP, 2005.
- Adrian Goldsworthy, Fall of the West: the death of the Roman superpower, Phoenix, 2010.
- W. M. Jongman, Gibbon was right: the decline and fall of Roman economy, in the book: Crises and the Roman Empire. Proceedings of the Seventh Workshop of the International Network Impact of Empire (Nijmegen, June 20-24, 2006),
  Freely available on Internet.

  (This paper checks Gibbon's insight with modern hard evidence).

To be sure, decline of mathematics, and of science in general, began several centuries before the decline of the Roman empire,
see on this:

- L. Russo, The forgotten revolution. How science was born in 300 BC and why it had to be reborn, Springer, 2004.

So decline in science was followed by a collapse of civilization.

Comment: After reading through about 13 comments, I got to your answer and thought "Finally, someone mentions historical aspects of the middle ages!" (often called the [Dark Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Ages_(historiography))), which at least for me was one of the 3 or 4 main topics in my high school world history class. Regarding the OP's question, to me the amount of mathematical pursuits done during this time is actually rather amazing (most of it in the middle east regions) given the harsh conditions and lack of resources for scholarly pursuits (time, travel, communication, etc.).

Comment: Note that these sources are about the decline of specific civilizations, but if the discussion is about mathematics as a whole it is hard to say that there was a global decline. Maybe OP should specify if this is about European mathematics.

Comment: @Mauricio: Yes, I was talking about the collapse of a specific civilization, which can be called Greco-Roman civilization. But the point is that it is THIS civilization which invented mathematics (in the modern sense of this word).

Comment: I do not want to argue here on the definition and scope of mathematics, but the undisputable fact is that it achieved very high degree of sophistication in Greece, and when we are talking of modern mathematics (or 17 century mathematics), it is inherited from the Greek one, not from the other varieties like Chinese one, for example.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, you can reasonably claim that Indian and Chinese mathematics didn't have a major influence, but you can't ignore the contributions of the Islamic mathematicians.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro While I agree with you in principle, I feel that there is a risk that your education, like mine, brushed everything from the Fall of Rome to the emerging struggle between Rome and Canterbury under the carpet. No Eastern Roman Empire, no Byzantium, no Islamic culture and /definitely/ no Avignon Papacy to challenge the narrative.

Comment: @Mark, no one denies the contribution of Islamic mathematicians, but as it is stated in the question the "development was very slow" in comparison with the Greek period and the period after 1600.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko slow with respect to what? Is this statement focused in Europe?

Comment: There is  a recent book by Lucio Russo (not yet translated) *The cultural collapse. The Roman conquest of the Mediterranean (146-145 a.C.)*, Carocci, 2022, that highlights the central role of the Roman expansion  in the decline of Western culture:
“The expansion of the power of Rome was accompanied by a severe cultural decline, so far largely ignored: the breakdown of science, the end of philosophical and linguistic research, the deep transformation of technology, that cut any link with science and written culture […] That collapse […] strongly conditioned the subsequent Western culture.”

Comment: https://www.amazon.it/tracollo-culturale-conquista-Mediterraneo-146-145/dp/882901222X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3CR83AJMSHY3R&keywords=lucio+russo+cultural&qid=1705489659&sprefix=lucio+russo+cultural%2Caps%2C164&sr=8-1

Comment: @BakerStreet: Thanks! I hope it will be eventually translated into English.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the question ought to be turned on its head: why did mathematical learning hit the accelerator in Ancient Greece and during the modern era in Western Europe (17th century to present)?

Some historians (e.g., [Walter Scheidel](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691172187/escape-from-rome)) have reasoned there were unique conditions in both eras and locations that helped foster the growth of mathematical and scientific knowledge: a fractured, competitive political geography that prevented a single authority controlling or stifling higher learning, and the presence of an economically prosperous, literate and educated class.

Humans are naturally curious and certainly human knowledge has expanded in other times and places (the Roman and Chinese empires, ancient Egyptian, Mesopotamian, Indian civilizations) but at a slower pace.

Comment: I would love to see a metric on this "acceleration", do you think that the acceleration was different during the Middle Ages under which criteria?

Comment: @Mauricio That's a good question and we have to be careful how we quantify terms like acceleration as well as time period and location (I know "Western Europe" is vague). The simplest metric would be counting the number of mathematicians who made a significant contribution. I think it's safe to say something special was happening at certain times and places in history, and at other times there was a steady trickle of new thinkers and innovations.

Comment: But that's where I do not get it. Do people really see a decline in the Middle Ages in the number of mathematicians and contributions? This period was as huge as in any other times I do not even see how would somebody would separate this age from the rest.

Comment: There were a few bright lights of learning during the Dark Ages in W. Europe, for example under Charlemagne's reign. But nothing like the Library of Alexandria existed until the first universities were established.  You're correct there was activity in other cultures during the 5th to 16th centuries, such as the Islamic world and Chinese Empire. But there was no Islamic or Chinese Scientific Revolution. I'm not belittling the contributions; they were invaluable. There was a missing ingredient that allowed science to flourish in Europe after a long dry spell.

Comment: I agree, as long as we focus on Europe. But to put a "slow" label on the Middle Ages just because there was no revolution is to me is like saying that in between the Scientific Revolution (from Copernicus to Newton) and the 20th century nothing happened or progress slow down because there was no revolution.

Answer (score 3):

There reason for the speed-up in the 1600s was Vieta's development of an algebraic formalism that allowed mathematicians for the first time to write down mathematical formulas rather than merely abbreviated phrases in natural language.  In your title you mention Descartes specifically, but several dramatic advances occurred before Descartes.  The names that come to mind are in alphabetical order Cavalieri, Fermat, Kepler, and others.

Comment: I didn't mean Descartes specifically but the era that he lived in. Cavalieri, Fermat and Kepler were from the same era i.e $1550 -1650$

Answer (score 2):

An aspect that has not been mentioned and is at least a partial answer is that progress must strongly depend on the number of people working in the field, which is the product of the population and the fraction of them working in the field. I'll focus on Europe here.

The population in Europe [doubled](https://www.encyclopedia.com/international/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/population-europe-early-modern-demographic-patterns) between 1500 and 1750; consequently, *ceteris paribus,* the number of people working in the field (I avoid the term "mathematician" because many scholars at the time were polymaths) should have doubled. Without any reference I can imagine that there was only a handful of people of the kind who would advance mathematics (or any other field) until maybe the early 1600s, in the entirety of Europe.

And the *fraction* of the population working in the field should also have increased. Life in Europe until the late middle-ages intermittently devolved into a fight for survival, often unsuccessful. Europe-scale famines and pandemics ravaged the continent in the middle-ages. While both didn't disappear later, they became less frequent.<sup>[1](https://books.openbookpublishers.com/10.11647/obp.0323/ch13.xhtml)</sup>.

With greater wealth and a growing surplus in food came the opportunity for a division of labor; professionals who did not directly contribute to food production could be sustained, like musicians, artists and scholars. At the same time, trade and crafts made education more important; in the cities, an educated citizenship emerged, among them teachers. Courts were able to host scholars like Leibniz and Voltaire.

That alone must be one reason the speed of mathematical development, like everything else,  picked up after 1500. Working hypothesis: That other regions, like the Arabian world, were more productive may be an indicator for greater prosperity.