# What were the obstacles that made the discovery of calculus very late?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, calculus, philosophy-of-science, book-recommendation

I wonder What were the obstacles that made the discovery of calculus very late ?

Why the discovery of calculus took so long? I know that some of the ideas and techniques of calculus appeared in ancient Greece, but they were not developed into a systematic theory until the $17$th century by Newton and Leibniz. What were the main obstacles or challenges that prevented the earlier mathematicians from discovering calculus?

One of the factors that I think might have played a role is philosophy. I have heard that some of the ancient and medieval mathematicians in Islamic world  were influenced by Aristotle’s philosophy, which had a negative view of infinity and rejected the concept of limit and convergence. Aristotle also preferred geometric methods over algebraic methods, which might have limited the scope and applicability of calculus. Is this true? How did philosophy affect the development of calculus? And is philosophy to blame for the discovery of calculus taking more than 1000 years?

Another factor that I think might have motivated the discovery of calculus is the problem of finding the area of a curve and the tangent line to a curve. These are two important problems in geometry and they require the concepts of derivative and integral. I know that Archimedes and other ancient mathematicians used the method of exhaustion to approximate the area of a curve, and that Fermat and other 17th century mathematicians used the method of adequality to find the tangent line to a curve. But why did it take so long to generalise and formalise these methods into calculus?

I know this question might have a long and complex answer, so I will ask for a book or reference if the answers are too long or complex.

Comment: The modern version of the calculus (Newton-Leibniz) started with the development of a specific symbolysm that is "algebraic-like" and this followed the development of modern algebra during the Renaissance. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768485/the-enrapturing-discoveries-of-our-field-systematically-conceal-the-analo) for a discussion of pre-modern algebra: how difficult was to "describe" a simple (in modern terms) equation.

Comment: "Aristotle’s philosophy... had a negative view of infinity and rejected the concept of limit and convergence." — Really?

Comment: @MichaelE2 well if that wasn't true then what philosophy that had a negative view of infinity

Comment: I wasn't questioning the attribution. I was questioning the three assertions as not completely accurate characterizations of Aristotle's philosophy.

Comment: Yeah that Aristotle thing could be removed from the question it is unprovable.

Comment: @Mauricio, I believe Aristotelianism is very relevant in connection with potential infinity vs actual infinity, as I elaborated in item 8 of my *answer*.

Comment: @MikhailKatz you draw a relation between Aristotle and infinities, note that pie writes something more elaborate. Also of course Aristotle was wrong, but isn't that the case with anything that came before? Clearly Newton's gravitation was wrong but that does not mean that his book was actively halting progress in gravitation for 400 years.

Comment: @Mauricio, would you agree that belief in flawed celestial models and the consequent burning of Copernicus at the stake may have had a deleterious effect on the development of science?

Comment: @MikhailKatz you know what? you are right. The authorities can be very drastic when you go against the paradigm, as with Copernicus. Very probably Aristotle was the main science paradigm for more than 1000 years. What I would like is that we also recognize is that progress in math does not happen in isolation. Despite being men of the church, Cavalieri and Copernicus challenged the paradigm successfully. Shattering a paradigm results from accumulated evidence and progress in those 1000 of years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to make several points with regard to this interesting
question.

1. The discovery of some Taylor series of trig functions by the Kerala
   school is a very impressive early breakthrough.  However, I believe
   the consensus of historians is that this does not in any way
   constitute significant progress toward the invention of something on
   the scale of the calculus.  Similar remarks apply to many other
   multicultural achievements touted at answers to some parallel
   questions.
2. Note that by the time of James Gregory, for example, many power
   series were already known, before the invention of the calculus.
   Today we tend to think of power series as part of the calculus, but
   historically they were available well before, including (as I
   mentioned) in Kerala early on.
3. With regard to Aristotle: The issue is not so much Aristotle
   himself but rather some Aristotelian doctrines as developed by
   medieval catholic theologians, including Aquinas.  One of such
   doctrines was the doctrine of hylomorphism which, so they claimed,
   stemmed from Aristotle.  Hylomorphism was viewed as the rival doctrine
   of atomism/indivisibles.
4. Hylomorphism since at least Aquinas was viewed as a theoretical
   background necessary for the catholic interpretation of the eucharist.
   Therefore indivisibles were viewed with great suspicion by some
   catholic theologians, including jesuit mathematicians such as Guldin,
   Tacquet, and others.
5. In a forthcoming article on Cavalieri, we show how religious
   resistance to his method of indivisibles (a precursor of integration)
   was the source of much of the opposition to his work and the work of
   his disciple Stefano degli Angeli.  Both Cavalieri and degli Angeli
   were jesuats.  The order was suppressed by papal bull in 1668.
6. In this sense, it can be said that philosophical and theological
   doctrines were an impediment to the development of the calculus, where
   ideas related to indivisibles were needed for the eventual
   breakthrough by Leibniz and Newton.  Such doctrines may have contributed
   to the delay that you mentioned.
7. You ask also for a book dealing with these issues.  While we don't
   have a book, there is a number of articles you can consult
   [here](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html).
8. You ask also about Aristotle and infinity.  Medieval scholastics interpreted Aristotle as introducing a distinction between potential infinity and actual infinity, and rejecting the actual sort.  This dogma was similarly used against scholars attempting to explore infinitesimal mathematics.  Thus, Paul Guldin wrote in his book that Cavalieri's indivisibles involve viewing a plane region as consisting of an actual infinity of parallel lines (Cavalieri himself denied this), and therefore meaningless, and therefore any results obtained by means of indivisibles are false.  Cavalieri and degli Angeli were never able to establish a school practicing these methods.  James Gregory, who visited degli Angeli in the 1660s, saw his books suppressed in Italy.

Comment: The problem about Kerala School is that it never made it outside Kerala... However other "multicultural achievements" did made it they were just not calculus.

Comment: Another impediment I see is the geometric-based math, it was not until the development of algebra and algebraic geometry that calculus was able to appear. Abstract analysis would appear later. Reading Newton you can see that calculus was mostly invented based on geometrical grounds (that required as you guess, the Middle Ages developments).

Comment: @Mauricio, I made a related point about Vieta at a parallel *question*.  However, I wonder how this could be squared with Archimedes' tremendous achievements in area calculations.  Apparently he managed to do it without "proper" algebra :-)

Comment: If Archimedes work on getting areas and approximations of $\pi$ are considered near-calculus then this never stopped, al-Kashi and al-Khwarizmi also continued to get better and better approximations by slicing things into polygons.

Comment: @Mauricio, I didn't say that Archimedes' work on areas is near-calculus.  Note by the way that Cavalieri did not use the Vieta formalism (unlike Fermat and others).  It is undeniable that Cavalieri's indivisibles were a major step toward integral calculus.

Comment: Cavalieri was Jesuate and from the specific period when infinitesimals where criticized. That did not stop him, doesn't that partially disprove that philosophy is not really an impediment?

Comment: @Mauricio : What I gather is that the 17th-c. Jesuits were in a kind of competition, within the church, with several other orders. Jesuits seem to have been 'hotter' on many kinds of disciplined belief, including the  mathematical as only one aspect, and they viewed the Jesuates as lax.  I don't think that the fact of Jesuate advances --  in what may have been a relatively liberal atmosphere before they were suppressed -- amounts to any evidence for lack of impediments facing those whose church  organizations had sterner disciplines.

Comment: I would like to point out that Galileo did some work on indivisibles too before Cavalieri.

Comment: @Mauricio: and therefore what?

Comment: @MikhailKatz It was just a comment as your post talks about Cavalieri. It is not related to any of the previous discussions.

Comment: Perhaps useful for those who don't quite follow: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala_school_of_astronomy_and_mathematics

Comment: I assume Mikhail Katz is referring to "Infinitesimal" by Amir Alexander. According to him, the reception of infinitesimal analysis in Italy was delayed by Catholic obscurantism. Apart from the fact that not every Catholic was a Jesuit and Italy was not the only Catholic region, there is a mathematical analysis manual from 1710 by the Camaldolese monk Guido Grandi: "De infinitis infinitorum et infinite parvorum ordinibus". Previously (1707 AD) Gabriele Manfredi published "De constructione aequationum differentialium primi gradus". Is this sufficient?

Comment: "Sufficient" to which end?  @M.Lonardi

Comment: @MikhailKatz This is sufficient to refute the thesis of Amir Alexander: if at the beginning of the eighteenth century a Camaldolese monk publishes a book of analysis in Pisa, it is not true that in Italy the Catholic Church has hindered development. There were mathematicians at work and if Euler was more skilled, so be it; but it is not because of the Catholic Church that Euler was more skilled.
Anyway, now I will write a response with what I think about the topic; after all, if Amir Alexander can publish a book, don't I have the right to write a post?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is decidedly against the current, and I will also write quickly from memory without looking for precise references. So, if the quality of this answer is considered low, I can accept it.
Let's start immediately with an important question: who invented infinitesimal calculus? Usually, the common response is: Newton and Leibniz. This would suggest that it was an invention in the air if two scientists (albeit mythical) had arrived at it together. Instead, if the author was only one, one could think of a stroke of genius, a sudden leap into the future.
Now, in my opinion, the author is clearly only one: Leibniz. I won't go into the "procedural" details, but the point is that it is too particular, too unstable, too contradictory (yes, contradictory) to be independently produced by two different people; in fact, it took about two centuries to give infinitesimal calculus a satisfactory foundation (first by replacing infinitesimals and infinites with limits, then finding an acceptable definition of a limit).
The second important question is: what is infinitesimal calculus? Leibniz explains it in "Historia et origo calculi differentialis": it is a way to represent algebraically the curves that Descartes could not represent with his system. So, the heart of the new system is given by the differential equations that are tasked with describing the curves that we now call transcendental.
Finally, we come to the initial question: why did it take so long? In my opinion, it's the opposite: between Descartes and Leibniz only a few years pass (1684 - 1637 = 47), which is a miracle. If Leibniz had never existed, I don't know how mathematics would have developed; perhaps it would have focused on infinite series.

Comment: This question is relayed to this https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/16120/why-was-the-development-of-mathematics-very-slow-between-ancient-greece-and-desc?noredirect=1&lq=1. I think the development of mathematics kinda stopped between ancient Greece and desecrates, there was not any major breakthrough that I know in this period.